# Why does SQLite3 not yield an error

Tags: python, sqlite

I am quite new to SQL, but trying to bugfix the output of an SQL-Query. However this question does not concern the bug, but rather why SQLite3 does not yield an error when it should.

I have query string that looks like:

```
QueryString = ("SELECT e.event_id, " 
    "count(e.event_id), "
    "e.state, "
    "MIN(e.boot_time) AS boot_time, "
    "e.time_occurred, "
    "COALESCE(e.info, 0) AS info "
    "FROM events AS e "
    "JOIN leg ON leg.id = e.leg_id "
    "GROUP BY e.event_id "
    "ORDER BY leg.num_leg DESC, "
    "e.event_id ASC;\n"
    )
```

This yields an output with no errors.

What I dont understand, is why there is no error when I GROUP BY e.event_id and e.state and e.time_occurred does not contain aggregate-functions and is not part of the GROUP BY statement?

e.state is a string column. e.time_occurred is an integer column.

I am using the QueryString in Python.

Comment: That is a "feature" of SQLite and MySQL. In MySQL you can correct that with the strict-mode setting in the server. Maybe in SQLite too...

Comment: Okay... Can you elaborate on the expected system-behavior of this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite and MySQL allow bare columns in an aggregation query.  This is explained in the [documentation](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html):

> In the query above, the "a" column is part of the GROUP BY clause and
>   so each row of the output contains one of the distinct values for "a".
>   The "c" column is contained within the sum() aggregate function and so
>   that output column is the sum of all "c" values in rows that have the
>   same value for "a". But what is the result of the bare column "b"? The
>   answer is that the "b" result will be the value for "b" in one of the
>   input rows that form the aggregate. The problem is that you usually do
>   not know which input row is used to compute "b", and so in many cases
>   the value for "b" is undefined.

Your particular query is:

```
SELECT e.event_id, count(e.event_id), e.state, MIN(e.boot_time) AS boot_time, 
      e.time_occurred, COALESCE(e.info, 0) AS info
FROM events AS e JOIN
     leg
     ON leg.id = e.leg_id "
GROUP BY e.event_id 
ORDER BY leg.num_leg DESC, e.event_id ASC;
```

If `e.event_id` is the primary key in `events`, then this syntax is even supported by the ANSI standard, because `event_id` is sufficient to uniquely define the other columns in a row in `events`.

Answer (score 2):

In a misguided attempt to be compatible with MySQL, this is allowed. (The non-aggregated column values come from some random row in the group.)

Since SQLite [3.7.11](http://www.sqlite.org/releaselog/3_7_11.html), using min() or max() [guarantees](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg) that the values in the non-aggregated columns come from the row that has the minimum/maximum value in the group.

Answer (score 1):

If `e.event_id` is a PRIMARY or UNIQUE key of the table then `e.time_occurred` is called "functionally dependent" and would not even throw an error in other SQL compliant DBMSs.

However, SQLite has not implemented functional dependency. In the case of SQLite (and MySQL) no error is thrown even for columns that are *not* functionally dependent on the GROUP BY columns.

SQLite (and MySQL) simply select a random row from the result set to fill the (in SQLite lingo) "bare column", see [this](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bareagg).